# Why does the `Console.Read()` keep jumping to another spot?

Tags: c#, if-statement, timer, console, character

I have a method that is used to ask which way a person would like to go in a `Console` game.

Afformentioned method:

private static void dirChoose()

```
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 7);
    Console.WriteLine("A mysterious voice says \"Which way will you go?\"");
    Console.WriteLine("Type");
    if (curLeft == false) { Console.WriteLine("(L)eft    "); }
    if (curUp == false) { Console.WriteLine("(U)p        "); }
    if (curRight == false) { Console.WriteLine("(R)ight  "); }
    if (curDown == false) { Console.WriteLine("(D)own    "); }

    Console.SetCursorPosition(49, 7);

    userDirInput = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 13);
    Console.Write("read as " + userDirInput);

         if (userDirInput == 'u' || userDirInput == 'U') { reDir = 1; userDirInput = 'y'; }//up
    else if (userDirInput == 'd' || userDirInput == 'D') { reDir = 3; userDirInput = 'y'; }//down
    else if (userDirInput == 'l' || userDirInput == 'L') { reDir = 0; userDirInput = 'y'; }//left
    else if (userDirInput == 'r' || userDirInput == 'R') { reDir = 2; userDirInput = 'y'; }//right
    else//anything besides
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 14);
        Console.WriteLine("You entered an incorrect direction. Please try again.");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(rWALL_STOP - 1, 3);

        doneBool = false;
        t.Elapsed += right;
        t.Start();

    }
}//dirChoose()
```

When answering the question of "Which way will you go?" it is SUPPOSED to read the first character that is entered. So were you to type the whole word "left" or "right" then it would have read 'l' and 'r'. Then it is supposed to change a number and let it do what its supposed to do. For some odd reason it jump to the second after reading the first, so it then adds the appropiate method to the timer and continues on its way.

Note:

```
static Timer t = new Timer(16);
public static char userDirInput { get; set; }

public static bool curLeft { get; set; }
public static bool curUp { get; set; }
public static bool curRight { get; set; }
public static bool curDown { get; set; }
public static bool doneBool{ get; set; }
```

So my question is "Why is the cursor jumping to the second character after the first? How do I fix it?"

Answer (score 1):

You could read the key as follows. Passing a value of false to the ReadKey() will echo the entered value back on the screen.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(false);
userDirInput = cki.KeyChar;
```

instead of

```
userDirInput = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
```

Comment: +1. But ... the parameter to `ReadKey` is backwards. As the documentation says, "**true** to not display the pressed key". I think you want `Console.ReadKey(true)`.

Comment: Just tried doing that a minute ago. Didn't work very well because it read it every time I hit the key (I understand thats what its supposed to do) but I need it to either just read the first letter or to read the entire string whic i guess I wouldn't have much of a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you seem to misunderstand the behavior of Console.Read().  When you call Console.Read(), you get the next character in the buffer.  If the user types "left" and then hits enter, you'll call console read to get the 'l', and then there will be 5 characters left in the buffer.  The next call will return 'e', then 'f', then 't', then '\r', then '\n'.

So if the user enters "left\r\n", the second time you call dirChoose(), it will behave as it should for unrecognized input.